# There are some problems with Tkinter threading in python 2.x

Tags: python, events, tkinter

I have a python code. I try Tkinter in python 2.x on Windows 10.
There is a window with size 500 x 500.
Then there is a Food class which  extend threading.Thread.
Food's task is to create 20000 ovals on the canvas.
And there is a Ship class, which task is to draw and move a blue rectangle on the canvas. Ship class does not extend any class.
But there is a problem. When I run the program, Food starts to create foods on the canvas. But when i move my ship, after some movements program gives an error and food stops to create ovals, but ship keeps to move.
What is the problem?
Error is:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\PC\EclipseWorkspace\PyTests\main.py", line 37, in run
    self.random_oval()
  File "C:\Users\PC\EclipseWorkspace\PyTests\main.py", line 30, in random_oval
    self.oval = self.canvas.create_oval(x-5,y-5,x+5,y+5)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2320, in create_oval
    return self._create('oval', args, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2305, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'expected boolean value but got "??"'
```

Below is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from Queue import Queue
import threading as th
import time
import random

wnd = Tk()
wnd.geometry("500x500+100+100")

canvas = Canvas(wnd, bg="yellow")
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

class Food(th.Thread):
    def __init__(self, canvas,food_count):
        canvas.update()
        self.width, self.height = canvas.winfo_width(), canvas.winfo_height()
        self.food_count = food_count
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.points = []
        self.random_oval()

        th.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def random_oval(self):
        while True:
            x = random.randrange(0,self.width)
            y = random.randrange(0,self.height)
            if (x,y) not in self.points : break    
        self.oval = self.canvas.create_oval(x-5,y-5,x+5,y+5)
        self.points.append((x,y))


    def run(self):
        count = 0
        while count != self.food_count:
            self.random_oval()
            count += 1
            time.sleep(0.001)

class Ship:
    def __init__(self,x,y, canvas):
        self.x, self.y = x,y
        self.canvas = canvas

        self.ship = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y,self.x+10,self.y+10,fill="blue")

    def move(self,event):
        direction = event.keysym.lower()
        if direction not in ["left", "right", "up", "down"] : return None
        if direction == "right" : self.x += 10
        elif direction == "left" : self.x -= 10
        elif direction == "up" : self.y -= 10
        else : self.y += 10
        self.ship = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y,self.x+10,self.y+10,fill="blue")

Food(canvas, 20000)
ship = Ship(50,50,canvas)
wnd.bind("<Key>",lambda e: ship.move(e))
wnd.mainloop()
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: tkinter code must all run in a single thread.  You don't need threads to create ovals on a canvas. Would you be interested in a solution that doesn't use threads?